# What does liquidate my fidelity ROTH mean?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, rollover, fidelity

I am trying to rollover my fidelity ROTH to Betterment and I've authorized Betterment to initiate the rollover.
The next step betterment requests is that they me to liquidate my ROTH, but I'm not sure what that means.
Do I just sell everything in there back to FDRXX (Fidelity cash reserves) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the opposite of "transfer in-kind." This would mean that you are moving assets as they are in the previous account, same stocks or mutual funds, etc.

In you case, they are requesting you transfer cash only. If you had a portfolio of stocks, for example, you'd have to repurchase each and every one, if you wished to keep owning them.